# Concatenating 2 lists into 1 C# question

Tags: c#, asp.net, list

I have 2 lists that are used to store int values in C#, and I want to merge these list, but I don't want duplicates in there. I.e. if list 1 has 1,2,4 and list 2 has, 2,3,5 I'd want 1,2,3,4,5 (don't matter about order) in my list. I've tried the Concat method, but that creates duplicates.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The LINQ [Union method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341731.aspx) should help:

```
var merged = list1.Union(list2).ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var newList = list1.Union(list2).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

There are probably some very clever and fancy ways to do this, but just a simple foreach loop would work. Just loop over list2, if the index doesnt exist in list1 add it.

Answer (score 0):

there are many many ways to do this.

```
myList<int> result = new List<int>( List1 ).AddRange(List2).Distinct();
```

Comment: @Daniel A. White absolutely, it is.  I am just saying that there are many ways to do this, with and without linq.

Comment: @Daniel A. White yes, i know. never said it wasn't. :)